# Cloning GITHUB project to ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I've had to wipe and reinstall my ubuntu server twice now due to failing and some how corrputing/locking my self out of the server when it comes to setting up the SSH.

I'm going out on a whim and hoping some one who reads this knows where to find an easy to follow tutorial for cloning a project to ubuntu using SSH as they dont allow HTTP cloning now.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first setup your ssh key following github [tutorial](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to create a key pair and add to your account

then in your ssh config(in your ~/.ssh folder) set up a config file to forward the ssh-agent after you ssh into a server. You can read more about this in github [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/using-ssh-agent-forwarding)

here is an example of a config file in the ssh folder:

```
Host example.com # or the server ip
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa # your secret key file
  ForwardAgent yes
```

When everything is done, try ssh into your server and git clone with the repo ssh url

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, as regards to the configuration file, I have to do that as my root user correct? When I tried in past with sudo user it always says unwriteable. And the  host would be my ubuntu server ip?

Comment: And just to confirm, the only places I need my ssh key is on my ubuntu server in an authorised_keys file and where github tell me to place it?

Comment: /home/dave/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: usekeychain
/home/dave/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: `Bad configuration option: usekeychain /home/dave/.ssh/config` usekeychain should have capital letter like the one I post, also you missing the private key file(it's not the config file) @DavidHenson The only place you need to generate your ssh key is on your computer(which you use to ssh into the server)